# Business Logic in stored procedure or application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, stored-procedures, architecture

I have an order form in my system. A user can edit the order form and save it to the database. In the form there is a checkbox field called "**Track order**" which if checked, adds the order id to the `TrackedOrders` table.

Now, my question is, which solution is better:

1. To use single Stored Procedure (`SaveOrder`) which first updates all the Order fields using an `UPDATE` statement and calls another SP (`AddTrackedOrders`) internally if the "isTrackedOrder" checkbox value = true.
2. Or to call the `SaveOrder` sp which will only update the order and then check in application code `if isTrackedOrder=true -> call AddTrackedOrders`.

Both calls have to be in the same Transaction! Means that if `SaveOrder` succeeds and `AddTrackedOrders` fails then SaveOrder would have to be rolled back as well.

I know that it is possible to create transactions in code but i'm not sure what are the implications of such a methodology.

Edit:

After a short research I've noticed that most people prefer to use TransactionScope. I'm still not certain how this is better as it makes the trasaction time much longer (and thus more error prone) and make multiple database roundtrips. Plus, you would probably need to add more stored procedures if their results control the flow of the business scenario...

Thanks all!

Comment: Better is not to use stored procedures at all, as long as it is possible.

Comment: But then how would i manage transactions in code?

Comment: There are no any difficulties in managing transactions from .NET code, whatever data access mechanism you use.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I'd put the business logic into the database if I'd run into duplicating if for different uplevel applications which for some reason cannot share components containing the business logic. It's more of a system design consideration.

Comment: @Filburt I Agree. My webservice contains a generic DAL method (Execute SP) which is called from remote clients that shouldn't have direct database access (kiosk machines). BUT, if i didn't have this limitation, would you suggest to put ALL business logic in application and manage transactions using TransactionScope? would it scale well considering the multiple database roudtrips and longer transaction time? Thanks!

Comment: Be careful ...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer executing business logic in *code*, not in *database* for various reasons (C# vs SQL, code versioning, re-usability...etc.).

You can wrap both code and stored procedure calls in a `TransactionScope` to execute both atomically:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Executes some business logic against the DB using a DB context
    ...

    // Executes some stored procedure here
    ...

    // commits transaction
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it require multiple roundtrips to the database?

Comment: @UriAbramson Does it matter? If you don't _currently_ have performances issues, writing maintainable code is more important IMO.

Comment: Is then leaving the transaction open at the database longer? And potentially causing lock contention at the database?

Comment: @ken2k, I don't know where this "no code in sql" comes from. If you have sql developers available to you and you're doing proper version control at the database level, i don't see why you'd need to draw such a hard line. Just a fyi, you can version control database objects. I think there are certain programming environments and teams where this "no code in sql" policy can be a good thing.. but this should really be addressed case by case. When you have db resources available... stick with sql. i think in this scenario, it would be wise to put this in the db.

Comment: Sorry.. you didn't draw a "hard line" I've been involved in other Code vs SQL conversation and it just bled over. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices: stored procedures, transactions in code, and unit of work pattern.

I would highly suggest implementing the Unit of Work pattern to manage transactions in code, vs. managing transactions in one-off situations or implementing stored procs.

Stored procs used to be the way to go, mostly due to performance. But with improvements to performance optimization with dynamic queries in recent SQL Server implementations, this is becoming less of a concern (though in some edge cases there still may be a small advantage). And with performance no longer an advantage, having the logic centralized in code w/ your other business logic makes more and more sense.

The Unit of Work pattern will allow you to manage your transactions via code much more easily, and it will support multiple layers of transactions (transaction within a transaction).

Unit of Work is much easier to implement with Entity Framework (or any ORM), but if you're committed to ADO.NET and not using an ORM, there are ways to do that. [This article](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/ado-net-the-right-way/#.Uo4VuOJTujs) gives a pretty good overview of implementing UoW w/ ADO.NET.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Dapper (microDAL). I find it much less binded to my database structure... more abstract. so if i do changes in the database i don't have to deploy a new version (with an updated entities structure). Stored procedures make it even more abstract so i still don't understand why not to use them :)

Comment: It looks like you can implement UoW w/ Dapper. Check out the [Github Readme](https://github.com/Pencroff/Dapper-DAL) where it talks about using Unit of Work w/ IoC.

Comment: Regarding using stored procs, an abstraction is an abstraction no matter which layer it lives in. If you have your query logic abstracted into a repository or other service layer, you still have the abstraction, but in C# code instead of SQL, and it lives with the rest of your logic. Personally, I find it cumbersome to have logic in both SQL and C#. It's also a bit easier to manage w/ source control.

Comment: Not if you're using ORM... Then your column names and table structures are binded to the application objects aren't they? How about the multiple roundtrips to the database?

Comment: I don't really understand that argument. How often do you change your database structure without needing to change your application objects? In my practice, this is very rare -- but maybe you're in a unique situation that requires database schema changes that don't impact your app. Regarding multiple round trips, I don't see this as an issue. If you're concerned about data in/out, my question would be are you sending/receiving more than you absolutely need?

Comment: About the roundtrips - in my stord procedures i sometimes have to run a select statement and change the flow of the procedure according to the result. This means that if i did it in code i would need to query the database twice (first, to check the result of the select statement, and then execute the corresponding SP/action).

Comment: As for the schema changes - right now, my 'data objects' structure depends on the schema of the result i get from my SP execution. this means that if i change any tables / views which my SP references, i would still be able to manipulate the way the stored procedure returns the data and this way avoid changing my data objects in the application. They act as sort of an interface between the application and the data rather than the actual data itself...